# EmailComposer in Phonegap 2.5.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am trying to add EmailComposer in Phonegap 2.5.0, have even tried adding it to 2.0.0 & 2.2.0 but getting the same error as below -

**

```
2013-04-03 15:17:57.748 email[1842:907] CDVPlugin class EmailComposer (pluginName: EmailComposer) does not exist.
2013-04-03 15:17:57.749 email[1842:907] ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

**

I have downloaded the plugin from - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposer

I have -

1. Installed MessageUI.Framework
2. Added EmailComposer to config.xml
3. Added *.h & *.m file to the plugins folder
4. And have the javascript file in WWW folder

still not able to find what is wrong.. Its really urgent as I have a due date, any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Rita

-----------------config.xml----------------------

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="EmailComposer" value="EmailComposer" />
    <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
    <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
    <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
    <plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />
    <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
    <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
    <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
    <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</plugins>
```

Comment: can you post your config.xml code? it seems it isn't right

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue doing ios development, the problem was that I copied the .h and .m files into the folder in finder.  I noticed that in xcode the 'Plugins' folder was empty.  I then removed the files from from the Plugins folder in finder and then just dragged and dropped them onto the Plugins folder in the xcode project.  This cured it.  Hope that helps - there must be a way to 'refresh' what xcode sees in the folders somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Open the .h and .m files and check that their contents is correct. Also make sure that they are labeled correctly and are actually EmailComposer.h or .m with that being the file extension and not part of the name.

Finally, put the plugin entry at the bottom of the plugin list(shouldn't matter but still, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer the EmailComposer.js file in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="EmailComposer.js"></script>
```